# Keeping content of a container together

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a definiton for every word in a text directly above each word (it doesn't matter if the definitions overlap. Later I will hide all the definitions and only display one at a time.)

The problem is that the last definiton and last word of a line don't stay together. The word always goes on the next line while the definition stays on the previous line.

how do I make them stick together?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fiddledidi/vtub581m/

```css
body .paircontainer {
  position: relative;
}

.def {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3.75em;
}

.def span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="line-height: 375%">
  <p>
    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>
    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>
    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>
    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>
  </p>
```

Comment: Uhm, what is the problem? It seems unnecessary messy, but it works as expected.

Comment: Actually it doesn't. When it goes over more than one line, the last pair of definition and word get separated. But nevermind. I already got an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `.paircontainer` be an `inline-block`. Also, the relative/absolute relations should be changed like in my snippet below, and I also adjusted the `bottom` setting of the absolute elements and assigned the `line-height` to the `p` tag instead of its parent:

```css
.x {
line-height: 375%;
}
.paircontainer{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.def {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="x">
    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>
    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>
    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>
    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>
        <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>
        <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>    <span class="paircontainer">
            <span class="def">
              <span>Definition
              </span>
    </span>
    <span>Word
              </span>
    </span>
  </p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. And so fast :)